# Asp.NET MVC view engines, why they don't support "View designer" now?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

With the asp.net MVC, we see a lot different view engines, like Razor, spark, webform etc.
I thought the idea of MVC is separating of data and view, I assume view part should be something that allows a designer to do some work, even after it is created by a developer. But I see now most if not all view engines introduce new syntax, not stick with html. The old web form, you can use "view designer" to see how a page looks like even with some code blocks, designer could at least move blocks and html elements around, but now with engine like Razor, you cannot even view a page in designer mode. So I don't quite get what is the point?
This came to me when I tried to search for a server side templating that allows end user do some changes on the page. I perfer something stick to pure HTML, maybe Spark is the one, but I am not sure. Please someone can give me some idea.

Thanks

Comment: What You See Is What You Get (WYSIWYG) doesn't work cross-browser with HTML. The HTML such designers generate is horrific. Writing semantic HTML and applying styles that works cross-browser is a job in itself and can, as of now, barely be generated by a tool.

Comment: The point is that proper web developers don't use WebForms' drag and drop tools. And XAML is *not* pure HTML. It's about as impure as it gets. The point of Razor is that you can cleanly inject dynamic values into otherwise pure HTML. It does a very good job.

Answer (score 0):

Views are meant for that. It will not static design. Markup will be generated on fly.
If you take razor as an example, you will have the combination of c# and html as code in view page. So, as you may be able to understand now, you cannot see the actual design until the c# and html execution goes hand-in-hand.

Hope it clarifies a little!